# У меня нету папки AppData\Local\Android

Tags: android, npm, react-native, mobile, sdk

Хотел запустить react native приложение на андроид без скачивания Android Studio. Подключил с USB кабелем к своему устройству и запустил приложение с помощью - npm run android. Вот что выводится:

Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. Default install location not found: C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk. Use ANDROID_HOME to set the Android SDK location.

Перехожу по адресу и вижу что и на самом деле у меня нет папки Android в AppData\Local.

Почему так получилось ? И что мне делать дальше... Прошу, помогите

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio скачивать не обязательно, но вот без Android SDK никак.
Скачать его можно отдельно отсюда (скролить до **Command line tools only**)
https://developer.android.com/studio

> Command-line tools are included in Android Studio. If you do not need Android Studio, you can download the basic Android command-line tools above. You can use the included sdkmanager to download other SDK packages.